# Where should I make AJAX and API calls in React.js function components?

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs

I've been learning more about React.js function components and have started transitioning one of my React.js applications to use them instead of the standard react components. In my react components I had been making AJAX/API call(s) in the `componentDidMount()` function. Since that function doesn't exist in function components I am unsure where to put them.

I couldn't find the answer on the React.js site, the [only page I could find on AJAX and APIs](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-ajax.html) shows making those calls with react standard components in the `componentDidMount()` function.

Comment: Search for useEffect() function

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is what React hooks gives us - ways to do side effects in functional components:

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html

from the doc page:

> If you’re familiar with React class lifecycle methods, you can think of useEffect Hook as componentDidMount, componentDidUpdate, and componentWillUnmount combined.

for example:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

function Example() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  // Similar to componentDidMount:
  useEffect(() => {
    //do an ajax call here
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <p>You clicked {count} times</p>
      <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>
        Click me
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use react-pure-lifecycle to add lifecycle functions to functional components.

Example:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import lifecycle from 'react-pure-lifecycle';

const methods = {
    componentDidMount(props) {
    //ajax call here
    }
};

const Channels = props => (
      <h1>Hello</h1>
  )

export default lifecycle(methods)(Channels);
```